# QWidget Transformation

Tags: c++, qt

I am writing an application using Qt and would like to have a "Metro Style" interface. Everything is finished except I don't know how to make the widget appear and disappear. For instance, in WPF you can animate *(UIElement.RenderTransform).(TranslateTransform.Y)* so that Y becomes zero or negative. How can I move the QWidget in a QGridLayout so that it can hide?

Example:
[image]

Comment: I think this is the kind of interface paradigm QtQuick is made for.

Answer (score 0):

After doing some research I figured out a way to do this. Instead of letting Qt do the layout I simply handled it myself via move and set width/height functions. Overriding resizeEvent made it so I could update the values in case the window was resized. Additionally I used setMask to ensure that the widget did not leak over to unwanted locations in the UI.